# Complex Cypher query using aggregated functions and math operations

Tags: neo4j, cypher, formula

I'm working with a Neo4j embbeded database, using Java API and Cypher queries, using a model of nodes and relationships like this:

```
MATCH (t:Task)-[:ASIGNED_TO]->(p:Person)
```

Now, the following fields o properties for each kind of node:

```
Task (id, estimated_time,closed, priority, evaluation, start_date, end_date)
Person(id,name)
```

Using this formula:

```
A = 3*count(B)+2*count(C)+count(D)
```

Where B are the tasks with priority 'High', C:'Medium', and D: 'Low'. I want a query that calculate A factor for a person (this is using a WHERE clause specifying its id). Summarizing: Take the person's tasks, know which of them have a custom priority, and calculate A using the previous expression. Of course I have tried with some queries like this:

```
MATCH (p:Person{id: 178})  //with the person with id 178
WITH p
MATCH (t1:Task)-[:ASIGNED_TO]->p
WHERE t1.priority = 'High'
WITH p, count(t1) as B
MATCH (t2:Task)-[:ASIGNED_TO]->p
WHERE t2.priority = 'Medium'
WITH p, B, count(t2) as C
MATCH (t3:Task)-[:ASIGNED_TO]->p
WHERE t3.priority = 'Low'
WITH p,B,C,count(t3) as D
RETURN p.id, (3*B+2*C+D)
```

And this return 0 rows, but if I try just with

```
MATCH (p:Person{id: 178})
WITH p
MATCH (t1:Task)-[:ASIGNED_TO]->p
WHERE t1.priority = 'High'
WITH p, count(t1) as B
RETURN p.id, B
```

It returns correctly that has 21 tasks with High priority. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Has the Person with id 178 tasks with all types of priorities? If not, try this:

> MATCH (p:Person{id: 178})
>   WITH p
>   OPTIONAL MATCH (t1:Task)-[:ASIGNED_TO]->p
>   WHERE t1.priority = 'High'   WITH
>   p, count(t1) as B
>   OPTIONAL MATCH (t2:Task)-[:ASIGNED_TO]->p
>   WHERE t2.priority = 'Medium'
>   WITH p, B, count(t2) as C
>   OPTIONAL MATCH (t3:Task)-[:ASIGNED_TO]->p
>   WHERE t3.priority = 'Low'
>   WITH p,B,C,count(t3) as D
>   RETURN p.id, (3*B+2*C+D)

Other option: Try use `PROFILE` command for getting more information about your Cypher query execution. ([link](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/how-do-i-profile-a-query.html))